# Error installing kivy with pip - Python

Tags: python, pip, kivy, failed-installation

I am trying to install kivy using pip and, but I'm getting the error:

```
c:\***\temp\pip-build-7e9b8p\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
     error: command 'C:\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need various dependencies to compile kivy on windows (well, on linux and osx too, but in those cases it's easier). I don't know what they are exactly. The difficulties with doing this are why we provide the portable package at kivy.org.

Comment: It very specifically says: `'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory` indicating that you don't have the OpenGL Extension Wrangler installed or it can't find it.

Comment: @inclement I have followed the instructions (on Windows 8.1 for python 3.5.2) at https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html# but am getting a similar message:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h'

Despite having filled the glew dependency:

Requirement already satisfied: kivy.deps.glew...

I see no obvious link to a "portable package".

Comment: Apologies, I now understand the use of wheels and have been able to use one to get kivy 1.9.x installed on my system and working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install libglew binaries for windows:

http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html